# Convert escaped string cookie into json object using javascript.typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, cookies

I am working on an angular 4 app and using [ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service) module to save and get the cookies

save cookie with following code

```
let defaultData = {   
            merchant_name : response.data.profile.business_name,
            role          : response.data.role,
            id            : response.data.merchant_id,
            is_default    : false
         };
let cookieData = JSON.stringify(defaultData);
cookieService.set('merchant_data', cookieData );
```

it works properly and saves cookie in following format

```
%257B%2522merchant_name%2522%253A%2522vk%2522%252C%2522role%2522%253A%2522merchant%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A103%252C
```

Now I am reading the same cookie with `cookieService.get('merchant_data')` and its works properly but I facing issue while converting the string to original json object.

I tried JSON.parse but its not working as its escaped string, is there any way to read these type of cookies strings and convert to json or array ?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() is exact opposite of JSON.stringify() and it should work.

The problem might come from ngx-cookie-service i would recommend using localStorage to accomplish same behaviour.

Like this :

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

More about [HTML5 LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)